# Weird crash related to a tableview reloading itself

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am only using -reloadData to reload my table, but for some reason it crashes every time we load this one table. This is only one of many tables in the app all handled by the same view-controller superclass:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x321effbc objc_msgSend + 16
1   UIKit                               0x31abd9c4 -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 540
2   UIKit                               0x31abcaa2 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1070
3   UIKit                               0x31abc22c -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 200
4   UIKit                               0x31a60d44 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 176
5   CoreFoundation                      0x36de4224 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 36
6   QuartzCore                          0x317ab37a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 210
7   QuartzCore                          0x317aaf92 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 210
8   QuartzCore                          0x317af114 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 220
9   QuartzCore                          0x317aee50 CA::Transaction::commit() + 308
10  QuartzCore                          0x317a6d7e CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 50
11  CoreFoundation                      0x36e59b44 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 12
12  CoreFoundation                      0x36e57d80 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 252
13  CoreFoundation                      0x36e580da __CFRunLoopRun + 754
14  CoreFoundation                      0x36ddb4d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
15  CoreFoundation                      0x36ddb39e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
16  GraphicsServices                    0x32ab6fe6 GSEventRunModal + 150
17  UIKit                               0x31a8b73c UIApplicationMain + 1084
```

None of the steps in the stack trace are from our code directly, so I'm lost. Why would it crash here?

Comment: When do you reload the table? Eg, in viewWillAppear or after some data has downloaded, etc.

Comment: I'm reloading in -viewDidLoad and then when I receive the "fetchedResultsControllerDidChangeContent" notification.

Comment: Try setting NSZombieEnabled YES and see if you are trying to accessed released object. It might not be related to reloading tableview data. Trying to access released object reproduce similar issues.

Comment: If it works with other tables, I'd assume that it's within the data or the way the cellForRowAtIndexPath method is setting up the cells.

Comment: Are you calling -reload from a background thread instead of the main thread?

Comment: This is all happening on the main thread. I've made -that- mistake before :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your TableView's delegate and datasource are set to nil in the dealloc methods of the viewControllers. I had the exact same when the system tried to call CellForRow.... for a tableview that was destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this identical trace using a nib to instantiate the row cell and found that I was accidentally instantiating a cell from a bad nib reference. I was instantiating the cell like so in the cellForRowAtIndexPath callback on the table data source delegate:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCellIdentifier";
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    [self.cellNib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
    cell = tmpCell;
    self.tmpCell = nil;
}
```

To fix I made sure in viewDidLoad I create the cellNib:

```
self.cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCellNib" bundle:nil];
```

And in viewDidUnload, kill the reference to it (this is the most important step):

```
self.cellNib = nil;
```